# Why would core data not persist to disk?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an app that uses core data and successfully writes to disk regularly when data is changed. For most users this works absolutely fine.

However, one person found they were able to use the app for several hours and only when they closed the app and opened it again, did they discover nothing had been saved.

There was no error, no crash. The app continued to be completely usable. It just hadn't persisted anything to disk.

When they continued to use the app the same thing happened, it wouldn't save anything to disk. The issue actually resolved itself (with no code changes) when that person simply rebooted their phone.

I'm wondering if this could be a disk space issue? The app is around 170mb on their phone and they have ~300mb of free space.

I'm open to any suggestions here. Personally I'd rather have the app crash than let someone continue to use it for hours at a time without them realising that nothing is saving to disk.

I am using Magical Record for my Core Data implementation.

I was using `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` and I've now switched to `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWaitWithError`. But I wouldn't even know what to check for on this as I've no idea if it was raising an error.

Comment: Might it be possible to give the user a build with extra logging enabled? Has the issue occurred again since the first time?

Comment: It hasn't happened again that I know of. I could possibly get them a  build with extra logging.

Comment: Reproducibility would be key here, and without reproducing the issue a logging build wouldn't be much help.

Comment: Could point to a bug with your code also.

Comment: Thanks yeah reproducing it would be ideal. At this point I have no idea how to though. I think I will try putting it on a device with low-memory and see what it does if it doesn't have enough space to save. But really I'm looking for any other ideas where to start.

Comment: If you are using nested contexts, there is a possibility that you may be saving the wrong context OR the saveToPersistentStore* methods are not recursing up the chain to the context with the PSC connected. This is the first I've heard of this type of issue, so my best suggestion is to have a look at your saves and see which ones might be disconnected, even accidentally.

Comment: The fact the issue corrected itself with no code changes by just rebooting the phone makes me think it seems very unlikely to be how i've wired up the Core Data stack. Obviously I can't rule it out until I can reproduce the issue. Could a validation issue cause it not to save? Or would that not even save in the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I can not be sure I've reproduced the issue on the user's device that reported the problem. I was able to reproduce a scenario where my app would continue to function – but not persist anything to disk.

I did this by manually creating an object that did not meet the validation rules of the Entity model.

When the context was attempted to be saved, it was spitting out an error but the application continued to function as if there had not been a problem.